# java ldap cross forest search

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I created two Active Directory forests (forest A/domain A and forest B/domain B) and created a two way forest trust between them.  I can login to domain A and query users from domain B by using Find in AD Users and Computers tool and vice versa.

When I tried to do a java ldap search from forest A with search base set to an OU in forest B, i got the invalid credential error:

engine: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580

I used the following configuration

```
Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION = "simple", 
Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL = Administrator@domainA.com 
Context.PROVIDER_URL = ldap://domainA.com 
Context.REFERRAL = "follow", 
searchBase = OU=ou1,DC=domainB,DC=com
```

on domain B, I already add Administrator@domainA to be a member of the Administators group so Administrator@domainA should have access to ou1 on domainB.

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @jasmin9891 did you find anything on this?